# Python Boto3: The IPv6 CIDR '2600:1f18:335f:f201::/64' conflicts with another subnet

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto3, amazon-vpc

I am fairly new to boto3 scripting, python and I have managed to decently write the below code for creating a vpc and multiple subnets in the same VPC. Here is my boto3 code.

```
        import boto3
        import ipaddress
        from itertools import islice

        def creating_the_vpc(cidr_block):
            ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
            ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
            vpc = ec2.create_vpc(CidrBlock=cidr_block, InstanceTenancy='default', AmazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock=True)

            response = ec2_client.modify_vpc_attribute(
                VpcId=vpc.id,
                EnableDnsSupport={'Value': True}
            )

            response = ec2_client.modify_vpc_attribute(
                VpcId=vpc.id,
                EnableDnsHostnames={'Value': True}
            )

            print("after creating a vpc with cidr block")
            vpc.create_tags(Tags=[{"Key": "all-vpc1", "Value": "MyVPC"}])
            vpc.wait_until_available()

            #vpc_response = ec2_client.describe_vpcs(VpcIds=[vpc.id])
            #ipv6_cidr_block = vpc_response['Vpcs'][0]['Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet'][0]['Ipv6CidrBlock']
            #print("this is ipv6 cidr block",ipv6_cidr_block)


           # print("VPC created with ID:", vpc.id)
            return vpc

        def calculate_subnet_ipv6_block(vpc_id):
            ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
            response = ec2_client.describe_vpcs(VpcIds=[vpc_id])
            vpc_ipv6_cidr_block = response['Vpcs'][0]['Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet'][0]['Ipv6CidrBlock']
            print(vpc_ipv6_cidr_block)
            #ipv6_cidr_block = '2600:1f18:7c90:bb00::/64'
            ipv6_address = vpc_ipv6_cidr_block.split('/')[0]  # Extract the IPv6 address part
            #print(ipv6_address)
            for i in range(1,100):
                sixth_seventh_chars = ipv6_address[18:19]  #Get the 6th and 7th characters as a string
                #print(sixth_seventh_chars)
                new_chars = int(sixth_seventh_chars, 16) + i  # Convert the string to an integer and increment it
                print("this is new chars",new_chars)
                new_sixth_seventh_chars = hex(new_chars)[2:].zfill(2)  # Convert the incremented value back to hex and zero-pad if necessary
                print("this is new 6th and 7th chars",new_sixth_seventh_chars)
                new_ipv6_address = ipv6_address[:17] + new_sixth_seventh_chars + ipv6_address[19:]
                new_ipv6_cidr_block = new_ipv6_address + '/64'  # Add back the CIDR prefix length
                yield new_ipv6_cidr_block


        def creating_the_subnet(vpc_id, cidr_blocks, availability_zone, subnet_name):
            ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
            ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
            vpc = ec2.Vpc(vpc_id)
            
            response = ec2_client.describe_vpcs(VpcIds=[vpc_id])
            vpc = response['Vpcs'][0]
            #print(vpc,vpc_id)
            ipv6_cidr_block_associations = vpc.get('Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet')
            ipv6_cidr_block = ipv6_cidr_block_associations[0]['Ipv6CidrBlock']

            print("this is ipv6###",ipv6_cidr_block_associations)
            print("ipv6cidrblock****",ipv6_cidr_block[:-2])

            ipv6_subnet_cidr = ipv6_cidr_block[:-2] + '64'
            print("this is ipv6 subnet cidr",ipv6_subnet_cidr)

            
            subnets = []
            
            for cidr_block in cidr_blocks:
                # Check if the subnet already exists
                existing_subnets = list(ec2.subnets.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'vpc-id', 'Values': [vpc_id]},
                                                                    {'Name': 'cidr-block', 'Values': [cidr_block]}]))
                print(existing_subnets)
                if not existing_subnets:
                    ipv6_cidr_block_generator = islice(calculate_subnet_ipv6_block(vpc_id), len(cidr_blocks))
                    new_ipv6_cidr_block = next(ipv6_cidr_block_generator)
                    # Create a subnet
                    response = ec2_client.create_subnet(
                        CidrBlock=cidr_block,
                        VpcId=vpc_id,
                        Ipv6CidrBlock = new_ipv6_cidr_block,
                        AvailabilityZone = availability_zone,
                        TagSpecifications=[
                            {
                                'ResourceType': 'subnet',
                                'Tags': [
                                    {
                                        'Key': 'Name',
                                        'Value': subnet_name
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    )
                    print("--------------------------after creation of subnet-------------", new_ipv6_cidr_block)
                    subnet_id = response['Subnet']['SubnetId']


                    # Add the subnet to the list
                    subnets.append({
                        'SubnetId': subnet_id
                    })


                    if new_ipv6_cidr_block is not None:
                        print("IPv6 CIDR block of VPC:", new_ipv6_cidr_block)
                        #response = ec2_client.modify_subnet_attribute(
                       #     SubnetId=subnet_id,
                        #    AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation={'Value': True}
                        #)
                        print("IPv6 address auto-assign enabled for subnet:", subnet_id)

                    else:
                        print("VPC does not have an IPv6 CIDR block associated.")
                          
            return subnets





        if __name__ == "__main__":
            vpc = creating_the_vpc('10.16.0.0/16')


            cidr_blocks = ['10.16.0.0/20', '10.16.16.0/20', '10.16.32.0/20', '10.16.48.0/20']
            subnet_names = ['sn-reserved-A', 'sn-db-A', 'sn-app-A', 'sn-web-A']

            for cidr_block, subnet_name in zip(cidr_blocks, subnet_names):
                creating_the_subnet(vpc.id, [cidr_block], availability_zone='us-east-1a', subnet_name=subnet_name)
```

I am trying to execute and it throws me conflicts with another subnet error while creating the second subnet, after creation of sn-reserved-A subnet in a VPC.
I have tried my best to calculate the ipv6 block to be assigned from the function calculate_subnet_ipv6_block but throws me the below even though i am trying to generate a new ipv6block for my second subnet in creating the subnet function,

```
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    File "/home/user-folder/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line                705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSubnet.Conflict) when   calling the CreateSubnet operation: The IPv6 CIDR '2600:1f18:335f:f201::/64' conflicts with another subnet
```

could somebody help with this and ultimately my goal is create all 4 subnets and proceed to create something like the details given in the below table?

```
        NAME CIDR AZ CustomIPv6Value
        sn-reserved-A 10.16.0.0/20 AZA IPv6 00
        sn-db-A 10.16.16.0/20 AZA IPv6 01
        sn-app-A 10.16.32.0/20 AZA IPv6 02
        sn-web-A 10.16.48.0/20 AZA IPv6 03

        sn-reserved-B 10.16.64.0/20 AZB IPv6 04
        sn-db-B 10.16.80.0/20 AZB IPv6 05
        sn-app-B 10.16.96.0/20 AZB IPv6 06
        sn-web-B 10.16.112.0/20 AZB IPv6 07

        sn-reserved-C 10.16.128.0/20 AZC IPv6 08
        sn-db-C 10.16.144.0/20 AZC IPv6 09
        sn-app-C 10.16.160.0/20 AZC IPv6 0A
        sn-web-C 10.16.176.0/20 AZC IPv6 0B
```